# Umarshal JSON response into one of two struct types in Go

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I am working with a 3rd party API endpoint that can return one of two top-level JSON objects for the same HTTP status code.  I have not been happy with the solutions I have found so far so I came up with the following solution using embedded types:

```
type TokenError struct {
    Error            string `json:"error"`
    ErrorDescription string `json:"error_description"`
}

type Token struct {
    AccessToken string `json:"access_token"`
    ExpiresIn   int    `json:"expires_in"`
    TokenType   string `json:"token_type"`
}

type TokenResponse struct {
    *TokenError
    *Token
}
```

With the above types, I can do a single unmarshal and some simple checks:

```
var tokenResponse TokenResponse
err = json.Unmarshal(body, &tokenResponse)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Error parsing response %+v\n", err)
}

if tokenResponse.TokenError != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Error fetching token: %+v\n", tokenResponse.TokenError)
    return
}

if tokenResponse.Token != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Successfully got token: %+v\n", tokenResponse.Token)
    return
}
```

I am wondering the following:

- Is this an anti-pattern or bad design for some reason?  (Assuming I don't expose that `TokenResponse` type outside of the package...)
- Is there some easier solution to this problem that I have overlooked?

Comment: Is there another way to determine which it will be? For example, a well-written REST API will return an error along with non-2xx response codes. Can you use the status code to determine which type to unmarshal into?

Comment: Why not embed TokenError in Token and unmarshal response in Token?

Comment: @Adrian I forgot to mention:  It is not a well written REST API.  Both responses come with the same status code / headers...

Comment: That's pretty unfortunate. Your options are to do as you've done, embed one in the other as @MayankPatel suggests, or try unmarshalling to one after the other and test after each to see if it delivered any values (note that if the fields don't match up but the JSON is valid, err will be nil but the values will be empty).

Comment: @Adrian: The problem I ran into with attempting to unmarshal one after the other is that when you pass `json.Unmarshal` a nil pointer, it still assigns a zero-valued struct to that pointer (which is not clean to test for) even if cannot unmarshal a single field.

Comment: I don't think it is an anti-pattern at all. In fact, your implementation seems like the most sensible pattern. This is one of the reasons I love how the json package deals with types composed of other embedded types.

Comment: Yes, but you can test the values - eg, try to unmarshal the error type, and if it's error value is the empty string, it's not an error, so unmarshal the regular response type.